# Deployment Error: We couldn't retrieve or load the information on the field: Record.OwnerId

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, deployment, page-layout, change-set

The changeset deployment is for a lightning record page, but it's a detail of a master-detail which is also in the deployment. I know that a detail does not have a Record.OwnerId, because it uses the Master's Owner ID. Now I don't understand I'm receiving this error if it's not supposed to have an OwnerId.[image: Error Message]

Comment: Welcome! Take a look at [ask] to see being specific is really helpful in getting an answer. You can [edit] your question to add some more information. For example, what exactly is selected in this change set (just the lightning page?), what does your lighting page metadata contain or what change was made on this page, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and in fact a better practice is to combine all these resources into a single changeset, instead split into two or a few changesets (Usually, one would keep all the dependencies in the 1st change set, like profile/object/field creation etc, and then have 2nd changeset that refers these items).  Of course, having too many changesets, may trigger test classes execution multiple times and one need to be cognizant of this and fine-tune the items within a change set accordingly.

For now, please try that approach of splitting this into 2 change sets and check if it works.